# How can I restrict the querys an IQueryable method filters on?

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter, where-clause, iqueryable

Is it possible to allow only certain properties to be filterable on a method that has exposed IQueryable in C#.

Alternatively, would I be able to monitor the where clauses and only allow through ones that are filtering on certain properties?

Comment: Not exposing IQueryable but using specification pattern is much easier and often recommended.

Answer (score 0):

`IQueryable` exposes the [`Provider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.provider.aspx) property, which is typed as an [`IQueryProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryprovider.aspx). This query provider is responsible for ultimately acting on the query and returning the appropriate results (although typically large portions of the necessary work are delegated to helper classes, it's the query provider that orchestrates the process).

Therefore the short answer to the question is: to insert custom logic on the query process, you need to control the `IQueryable.Provider` implementation and have it return a query provider that ultimately implements this logic.

If you intend to tackle building a custom query provider, take a look at this [MSDN walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx) and also this [excellent series of blog posts by Matt Warren](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx) for more information.